# Mercurial: How to compact/combine specified old revisions into one?

Tags: mercurial

I've got a repository. In the middle of its life-cycle I deleted a lot of unnecessary files from it  (I decided to keep  them unversioned).

```
hg remove
hg commit
```

The repo grows bigger and bigger.

And I decided to get rid of old revisions the from initial one to the revision where lot of files were removed (let's name it X).
Other words I want combine these revisions (from the initial to the X) into one initial revision.

But same time to keep the history of the following revisions (X+1, etc..) as they are.

I googled for the solution, but failed.

And found nothing clever than do this:

```
hg init newrepo
cd oldrepo
hg archive -r X newrepo
hg export -r X+1: -o "~/patches/%R-%h.diff"
cd newrepo
hg commit -A -m 'initial release (after archiving)'
hg import ~/patches/*.diff
```

And damn it, after few successfully applied patches
I receive:

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at xxx
Hunk #2 FAILED at xxx
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file xxx.rej
abort: patch failed to apply
```

What I do wrong?

I've got 1 repo without branches (to be more exact to the revision X all branches were merged).

The second solution was 
* hg convert to svn
* hg convert to mercurial from revisiob X+1

Failed with python backtrace (probably it was caused by our repo has about 3K files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out files from repository, you want to use `hg convert` (Mercurial to Mercurial) with `--filemap` argument (see documentation for more details). Keep in mind the affected changeset IDs (and those of all their descendants) will change.

Comment: Interesting, first tests with exclude files show good results. Thanks!

Comment: It compacted the size of the repo, but the time of hg archive remain almost the same

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Collapse](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension) extension which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, it suits, but unfortunately it died. I posted a bug report

Answer (score 0):

You can [fold changesets with MQ](http://unitstep.net/blog/2011/01/26/folding-changesets-with-the-mercurial-queues-extension/), or use [histedit extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension)